# Micro:bit makecode how to import dictonary methods

Tags: python, makecode

im trying to use the .value() method in my makecode code but it comes up with an error [image]

i need to use that function in my code if you know how to import it that would be great. thanks

Comment: What is the result of dir(morse)?

Comment: unknown function dir